# Can we submit apps for commercial purpose with student account on Microsoft App Store?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store, dreamspark

I'm developing apps for Windows Phone 8, and I've a Microsoft Student Developer account registered at DreamSpark, so my question is can I submit apps for commercial purpose(to make money) with this account. So, please provide me sufficient and helpful knowledge for this.
Thanks in advance, any suggestion will appreciated.

Comment: Guru amit how r u?Yes you can do it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! Microsoft even encourages you to do this.

Section 4.c in the [EULA states](https://www.dreamspark.com/Institution/DS-EULA.aspx):

> If you use the software to create software programs, you may only commercially use or distribute them upon the purchase of appropriate commercial license(s) for the software. You may however submit software programs that you create using the DreamSpark Standard Subscription software **to Microsoft app stores, including for revenue.**